# Correlation function of excited states in the Ramond sector of 2 d free fermion?

Tags: string-theory, conformal-field-theory

$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{|#1\rangle}$

I'm hoping to find an algorithm to do three point function calculation for generic excited states in the Ramond sector of 2d free fermion.

In the NS sector, it's straightforward to use the Wick contraction to extract the result. For the R sector, modes are integer modes. In some sense, these modes don't have a clean correspondence to the free fermion (as compared with the NS sector). Are there any good reference for the R Sector calculations?

What I have in mind is to bosonize the excited states in R sector first and evaluate the correlation function using the free boson techniques. For example, suppose I'm bosonizing the excited states
$\psi_{-1} \ket{\sigma_+}$

I would do the following
$\psi_{-1} \ket{\sigma_+} = \int e^{i\phi} e^{\frac{i\phi}{2}} z^{-\frac{3}{2}}dz$.

Then take the OPE of exponential operators
$e^{i\phi} e^{\frac{i\phi}{2}}\sim z^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and do the integral
to extract
$\psi_{-1} \ket{\sigma_+}  \rightarrow e^{\frac{3i\phi}{2}} $

Similarly for $\psi_{-1} \ket{\sigma_-}$, I would get the corresponding bosonized operator $e^{\frac{i\phi}{2}}\partial \phi$.

For more complicated cases, say $\psi_{-3}\psi_{-4}\psi_{-5}\psi_{-6}\psi_{-1} \ket{\sigma_-}$. My algorithm asks me to do one extra OPE calculation for each new mode. I agree that I only need to pick out the term containing the pole. I could imagine there will be a lot of derivatives appearing for higher mode. Is there a faster way?

Comment: Have you considered doing it on Grassmann phase space?

Comment: @flippiefanus This is my first time hearing this terminology. Do you have any suggestions for the reference?

Comment: Any QFT textbook that discusses fermion fields should talk about Grassmann variables. The Grassmann phase space concept is a bit more specialized.